# Change array order according to value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array and I want change it's order.
    Following is an my array

```
        [1] => Array
                (
                    [A] => 25/02/2016
                    [B] => ZPO
                    [C] => 2
                    [D] => 3
                 )
        [2] =>array (
                    [A] => 25/02/2016
                    [B] => RTN
                    [C] => 2
                    [D] => 3
                )  
       [3] =>array (
                    [A] => 25/02/2016
                    [B] => ZPO
                    [C] => 2
                    [D] => 3
                )
```

index [2] array should be come at last because it contains value [B] = RTN
Means I want to reorder this array if [B] index contains value **RTN** should be come at last

Final output should be

```
  [1] => Array
                    (
                        [A] => 25/02/2016
                        [B] => ZPO
                        [C] => 2
                        [D] => 3
                     )
            [2] =>array (
                        [A] => 25/02/2016
                        [B] => ZPO
                        [C] => 2
                        [D] => 3
                    )  
           [3] =>array (
                        [A] => 25/02/2016
                        [B] => RTN
                        [C] => 2
                        [D] => 3
                    )
```

Comment: did u tried anything?

Comment: I havent tried anything. I am not able find any way

Comment: what is the business logic of this reordering?otherwise just grab the arraykey & unset them & then push into the array again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

```
foreach ($aArrayToSort as $iPos => $aArray) {
    if($aArray['B'] == 'RTN'){
        $aArrayToSort[] = $aArrayToSort[$iPos];
        unset($aArrayToSort[$iPos]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want that RTN records. I dont want to unset that

Comment: I'm adding it to the end of the array then removing it. Saved storing it in a temp var. UPDATE - noticed an error in code, see what your saying now.. Updated accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can use `usort` and provide a function:

```
usort(
  $array,
  // compare function for value 'B'.
  function($arr1, $arr2) { 
      // descending order ($arr2, $arr1). for ascending compare ($arr1, $arr2)
      return strcmp($arr2['B'], $arr1['B']);
  });
```

Comment: This sorts the arrays ascending, OP wants it descending. You need to switch `$arr1['B']` and `$arr2['B']` inside `strcmp()`

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it accordingly!